# Remove width and height from svg using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following block of code (I remove the path from the svg so don't mind that)

```
<div class="c-svg">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="ie-svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="35" height="35" data-name="Layer 1"><path></svg>
</div>
```

It has the following classes

```
.c-svg svg {
    width: 60% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}

.c-svg svg {
    fill: #fff !important;
    width: 2.5em !important;
    height: 2.5em !important;
}
```

How would I remove the width and height from these classes. I can't delete the class unfortunately, but I need to remove the classes, so that when I add a class via JS, I can use them.

It needs to be IE compatable

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  I'm guessing "just remove the `width` and `height` rules from the css" isn't what you're looking for, because that would be too trivial -- what are your actual constraints?

Comment: I'm looking to remove the height and width using js. I can't remove the css as it's global styles effecting loadsa if sites. I'm using JS to set specific conditions where the width / height is removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your css weren't using `!important` for everything this would be much simpler; normally inline styles override those set externally, so any js-induced changes in style would take precedence over those in the CSS file.

Since you are using `!important`, you would need to set the inline style to an `!important` precedence as well (but note this particular method will overwrite any other inline styles already applied to the element):

```js
document.querySelector('.c-svg svg').style.cssText='width: 400px !important'
```

```css
    .c-svg svg {
        width: 60% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
    }
    
    .c-svg svg {
        fill: #fff !important;
        width: 2.5em !important;
        height: 2.5em !important;
    }
    
    /* Adding so changes are visible: */
    svg {border: 1px solid}
```

```html
<div class="c-svg">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="ie-svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="35" height="35" data-name="Layer 1"><path></svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could skip the javascript and add another rule to your CSS with a more specific selector (though it, too, will need to be `!important`):

```css
.c-svg svg {
  width: 60% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}

.c-svg svg {
  fill: #fff !important;
  width: 2.5em !important;
  height: 2.5em !important;
}


/* Adding so changes are visible: */
svg {
  border: 1px solid
}

/* override with a more specific selector: */

div.c-svg svg {
  width: 400px !important
}
```

```html
<div class="c-svg">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="ie-svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="35" height="35" data-name="Layer 1"><path></svg>
</div>
```

This is all a pretty good example of why `!important` should be avoided whenever possible; if you need a rule to override another it's better to use a more specific selector instead of brute-forcing it with `!important`.

Answer (score 1):

You can literally remove the class from the div using JS.

If you add an Id to the element you can remove and add a class to it with ease:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.remove('MyClass');
```

However, you can always just modify the height and width with JS or, even better, modify its `display` so it is `none`.